# Global variables getting reset in PHP

Tags: php, variables, reset

I have a script with 3 (relevant) global variables used for keeping track of errors that happen while I'm checking user data. The function that handles them looks like this:

```
$errors = '';
$errorNo = 0;
$erred = false;

function addError($errorMessage) {
    global $errors, $errorNo, $erred;
    if (!$erred) {
        $erred = true;
    }
    $errorNo++;
    $errors .= $errorNo . ". " . $errorMessage;
}
```

Assume I call `addError()` more than once, `$errors` will have a value of `''` even though it was just modified by the `addError()` function. Not only that, but the variables `$errorNo` and `$erred` are also being reset to the values I first initialised them with.

I checked my code thoroughly to see if `$error` or the other variables were being modified somewhere else but to no avail.

Now, here's were it gets even weirder. To make sure that they weren't being modified by anything else (I have a external library imported using `require()`) I made a class called `errorHandler`.

```
class errorHandler {
    private $errorCount = 0;
    private $erred = false;
    private $errors = '';

    public function addError($errorMessage) {
        $this->erred = true;
        $this->errorCount++;
        $this->errors .= $this->errorCount . ". " . $errorMessage;
    }

    public function getErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

The values of `$errors`, `$errorCount` and `$erred` are not being stored after the function finishes. If I echo the value inside the function it will be the value I just assigned to it, however if I echo it prior to the assignment, it will be the value it had when it was initialised.

Any ideas where the problem might be? Thanks.

EDIT :

The `errorHandler` class is used as follows:

```
$errorHandler = new errorHandler; // Earlier in code

function addError($errorMessage) { // Function has name to avoid renaming
    global $errorHandler;
    $errorHandler->addError($errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share an example of that class being used? (with your debugging)

Comment: If you mean the external library: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I mean the usage of the "errorHandler" function you've written.

Comment: Aren't you trying to access these values within separate (http/page) requests?

Comment: The structure is basically every php file has this line at the top require('includes/header.php') and this line at the bottom require('includes/footer.php') and the errorHandler class is in header along with the above mentioned variables and functions.

Comment: No. They're being accessed within the same request but across multiple files.

Comment: Global means they exist in the global scope of the currently running script. They are reinitialized when running the script again (By a new page request). If you want to keep the values for re executions, store the values in a session or pass them through.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be **not** that the variables were getting reset (as you might have expected), but, this is a mistake that can be learned from for others I'd hope.

Basically I had a function `checkLength()` in an if statement like so:

```
if (checkLength($stringOne) && checkLength($stringTwo) && checkLength($stringThree)) {
```

The checkLength statement would check the length of the string and return false if it was too short or too long, but before that would add an error using the `addError()` function:

```
function checkLength($string) {
    if (..
    ..
    else {
        addError("Too short/long");
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I didn't realise was that as soon as the if statement has **one false value** (since I had the && operator) it would **not** run checkLength on the second or third string, hence not adding the error, causing me to believe that only one of the errors was being logged.

**Lesson here:** Store return values of functions in variables where possible then check the value of the variable rather than the return value of the function. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's why you were asked for code and not for describing it.

Comment: Please change the topic because this is not about global variables being reset.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a POST request is made, the PHP file is processed again, which means the code is run from the beginning. Hence the values of the variables are reset every time.

To get around this, you could maintain global variables in a javascript file and every time you call this function from the javascript file, change the value of the variables in the js file. Those values won't change every time a request is made.

Comment: You are correct on why it's failing, And your fix would work. Though you could also use a JSON, or a CSV or other file type as well. And given that this file is only there so the PHP script can remember the values from the previous runs, using a file type PHP can read natively will be less hassle. as you have to format the file in a special way for JavaScript to read it and it's not a native format for PHP to read back in either so you'd need custom writing and reading functions as opposed to if you used JSON or CSV there's built in functions to read/write data to those file types.